# Connecting to EGDI WFS in QGIS 3.28 fails

Tags: qgis-3, vector, wfs, features

I'm trying to connect with the EGDI WFS (https://data.geus.dk/egdi/wfs/?whoami=youremail&typenames=egdi_mineraloccurrences_inspire) in QGIS.

After creating a new connection in Data Source Manager > WFS > New connection, i get this message :

```
Download of capabilities failed: Error transferring https://data.geus.dk/egdi/wfs/?whoami=ivenpepa@gmail.com&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=2.0.0 - server replied:
```

I've downloaded the gpkg file from EGDI Map Viewer but the schema is not the same as Map Viewer.

How to access to the data of EGDI WFS ? Is there another server to get those features?

[image]

Comment: looks like a broken mapfile on the server

Comment: I've raised the issue with the platform developers